# Android use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to remove USB device

Tags: java, android

I want to remove usb storage by using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().
                   exec("vdc volume unmount /mnt/usb_storage/USB_DISK0")
```

but p.waitFor() Returns 4.

So
any ideas to remove USB?

Comment: Is your device rooted? I'm fairly sure messing with mounting requires root priviliges.

Comment: Does the "app" have permission to run that command?  Is the command correct?

Comment: This command is correct when i use adb shell, Does this need permission to run? @StephenC

Comment: Given what it does, I expect so.  I couldn't find any online documentation to confirm this though.